# Ignore argument in filter function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function and I would like for this function to ignore the conditions applied to filter when the respective argument is not called.

Example:

```
dataset <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))

topcm <- function(data, feat1, feat2) {
  data %>% filter(a == feat1 & b == feat2) }

topcm(dataset, 2, 5) #should return only the second line of dataset

topcm(dataset, feat2 = 5) #I want it to return the second line as well, but it will instead give an error. I want it to still be able to filter, ignoring the conditional that isn't specified as an argument.
```

I know I can apply some "if"s to check if the arguments exists and break or continue from there, but if there are lots of arguments, I would need to do it one by one. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Try with `is_missing` or `missing_arg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using defaults on the variables.  For example,

```
topcm <- function(data, feat1 = data$a, feat2 = data$b) {
  data %>% filter(a %in% feat1 & b %in% feat2) }
```

The idea is this:  the default value of `feat1` is the expression `data$a`, which will be a vector containing all the values in column `a` of whatever dataframe was passed as `data`.

If you don't specify a value for `feat1`, the default will be used, and `a %in% feat1` will always be `TRUE` because `a` and `feat1` will be the same thing.

If you do specify a value, the default will be ignored, and the test will only be `TRUE` for those values you pass in as `feat1`.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution and Akrun's work and are simple ones. Could you explain me why in your solution the function filter ignores the missing argument 'a' when I call topcm(dataset, b = 5)?

Comment: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

An easier option is to have `...` as arguments and pass expression as argument.  Otherwise, we may need to evaluate with `is_missing` `maybe_missing` and it can be messier when dealing with lots of arguments

```
topcm <- function(data, ...) {
   data %>%
       filter(...) 


  }

topcm(dataset, a==2, b ==5) 
topcm(dataset, b == 5)
```